# Create a list from another

Tags: list, kotlin

Let say I have some values in a List. I would like to return another list with a new element

```
fun newList():List<Int>{    
    val values =listOf<Int>(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    return 7::values; // something like that
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Kotlin lists have [the `plus` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#operator-overloading) overloaded [in `kotlin-stdlib`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html), so you can add an item to a list:

```
val values = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
return values + 7
```

There's also an overload that adds another list:

```
val values = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
return listOf(-1, 0) + values + listOf(7, 8)
```

Note that in both cases a new list is created, and the elements are copied into it.

For [`MutableList<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/) (which has mutating functions, in contrast with `List<T>`), there is a [`plusAssign` operator implementation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus-assign.html), that can be used as follows:

```
fun newList(): List<Int> {    
    val values = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    values += 7
    values += listOf(8, 9)
    return values
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A different approach by using spread operator. Maybe in some case would be simpler than using `+` sign or `mutableListOf`

```
fun newList(): List<Int>{
    val values = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    return listOf(7, *values.toTypedArray(), 8, 9)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
fun newList():List<Int>{    
    val values =listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6) //Type can be inferred
    return values.plus(7)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a Scala-like with `for` and `yield`. It's pretty good in - currently experimental - coroutines :

```
fun testYield(max:Int): List<Int> {

    val values = buildSequence{
        for (i in 1..max){
            yield(i)
        }
    }
    return values.toList();
}
```

Or in shorter way:

```
fun testYieldFast(max: Int) = buildSequence {
    for (i in 1..max)
        yield(i)
}.toList();
```

It allows fast immutable lazy construction, where frequent concatenation are usually slow with immutable lists.